# Atomic branching and tagging with SVN and Subversive

Tags: svn, version-control, branch, revision, subversive

I'm new to SVN. Recently in my company we're testing it along with other VCS to decide where to migrate from CVS. The only thing that is really bugging me about it are the revision numbers for one single operation, which are not always atomic.

I use MyEclipse with the Subversive plugin. Commits are OK among projects. If I modify a set of files in different projects and then commit, they end up as changes under the same revision number which is what's expected. However, when I branch or tag, every single project is tagged or branched with a different and sequential version number. If I have ten projects and I branch them, I get numbers for each one like 37, 38, 39, 40... 46. If I use the copy command on the machine where the repositories are, I don't have this problem.

What I have found so far is that some people had this issue but with commits in general. For this issue they were told to use the SVN Kit Connector. Although it didn't specifically address my issue, I checked that and it's the connector I'm using.

Why when I branch or tag a list of projects, selecting them all, right clicking and selecting team > branch, they are commited separately instead of in just one commit operation?

My software versions are:

- SVN 1.6.11 running on Red Hat Linux 6.4, installed using Yum, with the repositories served by Apache 2.2 (for LDAP authentication)
- MyEclipse IDE 2014
- Subversive plugin 3.0.0
- SVN Kit connector 1.7.14

Comment: In Subversion, *repositories* have revision numbers that are sequential. Each committing operation yields a new revision number. Tags and branches are really just ideas, or better, copies of code. That you got right. Other than that, what is your question?

Comment: Why if I branch a list of projects in the same operation, every project is commited separately? I end up with a revision number for each project. If I check the resulting revisions in the history, I see they are revisions per project. I expected that creating a branch was atomic too.

Comment: That should not be the case, actually. If what you describe is true, the `svn log` command should show multiple revisions with the same "commit message" (the "log" entry, so to speak) if it's issued against the repository root (you can do that with `svn log svn://example.com/my_repo/`). Are you actively "clicking" to commit once or are those separate actions per project? Also, chat might be recommended here. I don't dare "answer" the question until I know what to answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be either an issue or a (weird) feature of the Subversive plugin.

The solution is to just create the branches or the tag from the SVN Repositories view. If you are going to create them from the package explorer or the navigator, don't use the working copy as it is. Create them always from an already commited revision.